# .NET Core for Linux with dockers - create docker image

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I want to create a docker image for code I have written in .NET Core (C# Visual Studio 2017), that can be run on Linux.

The steps - I create a new file, such as hello world:

```
using System;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

The docker file (for Windows), which had been tested and works:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/myApp.dll"]
```

The docker file for linux:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Receive.dll"]
```

The above does not work well.

When I run (in command prompt. Linux container):

```
docker build . -t myapp_linux
```

I got the message:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder786597608/publish: no such file or directory

Also, tried changing to configuration to something like:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Receive.dll"]
```

The above doesn't work either, and I got the message:

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: The windows docker image contains the dotnet sdk, so it can run dotnet restore and publish. The Linux image doesn't contain the dotnet sdk, it contains only the runtime. hence it can't run the restore and publish commands.

Comment: So its better to run the restore and publish command on a dev/build machine and just copy the output to docker image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the restore and publish command outside of docker file e.g. PowerShell first
and then just copy the output to docker, in docker file.

1- First run in cmd or powershell:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -o ./publish
```

2- In your docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Receive.dll"]
```

3- Build docker image

4- Run docker container

Comment: Thanks. The dotnet restore run (do I need it?), and I did publish, but I after build I got the message: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from

Comment: `dotnet restore` will restore nuget packages if you are using any.

Comment: If you have visual studio on your machine you should already have the sdk installed in your machine

Comment: you can run `dotnet --list-sdks` to verify that the sdk is installed on your machine

Comment: Thank you. I take it for granted. Docker is now working. There may be quite difference between sdk version 2.0 (was already installed) and sdk version 2.1 (which fix the issue).

Comment: "You should run the restore and publish command outside of docker file e.g. PowerShell first and then just copy the output to docker, in docker file" why do you say that? Shouldn't you be building your code in an isolated environment like docker to isolate it from the rest of the system before you deploy it?

Comment: @omajid You can if you want to, and it's probably a good idea. But you don't have to.

Comment: @omajid won't that increase the size of your deployable image? if you have sdks and other stuff installed on it just for builds?

Comment: @omajid also in this case it was clear that the linux image didn't have the sdk installed, so it was not capable of running the restore and publish commands

Comment: @AmanB Don't the exact same concerns apply to the "Windows" docker image? I am just really confused why you think any of those points are unique to the "Linux" dockerfile. IMO, you should use one dockerfile. If you want to trim it, sure, do it. But then use it on Windows too.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using different `Dockerfile`s? The whole point of containers is to get a consistent environment. Use the one you are using on Windows (which you know works), everywhere:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/myApp.dll"]
```

There's a number of advantages to doing this:

1. You are building the code same way on Windows and Linux. No more operating system differences, like the ones you are running into.
2. If you care about reproducible deployment via containers, don't you want to build in a reproducible environment too? Otherwise, as you are experiencing, what is installed on your OS affects how your code is compiled and executed.
3. No more worrying about keeping `Dockerfile` and other versions in sync. You are using `2.1` on Windows but `2.0` on Linux. That's probably going to cause some build or runtime issues. Not to mention 2.0 is actually out of support and wont get security fixes.